# Amazon CloudSearch returns false results

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch, text-search

I have a DB of articles, and i would like to search for all the articles who:
1. contain the word 'RIO' in either the title or the excerpt
2. contain the word 'BRAZIL' in the parent_post_content
3. and in a certain time range

The query I search with (structured) was:
`(and (phrase field=parent_post_content 'BRAZIL') (range field=post_date ['2016-02-16T08:13:26Z','2016-09-16T08:13:26Z'}) (or (phrase field=title 'RIO') (phrase field=excerpt 'RIO')))`

but for some reason i get results that contain 'RIO' in the title, but **do not** contain 'BRAZIL' in the parent_post_content.

This is especially weird because i tried to condition only on the title (and not the excerpt) with this query:
`(and (phrase field=parent_post_content 'BRAZIL') (range field=post_date ['2016-02-16T08:13:26Z','2016-09-16T08:13:26Z'}) (phrase field=name 'RIO'))`

and the results seem OK.

I'm fairy new to CloudSearch, so i very likely have syntax errors, but i can't seem to find them. help?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `phrase` operator but not actually searching for a phrase; it would be best to use the `term` operator (or no operator) instead. I can't see why it should matter but using something outside of how it was intended to be used can invite unintended consequences.

Here is how I'd re-write your queries:

Using *term* (mainly just used if you want to boost fields):
`(and (term field=parent_post_content 'BRAZIL') (range field=post_date ['2016-02-16T08:13:26Z','2016-09-16T08:13:26Z'}) (or (term field=title 'RIO') (term field=excerpt 'RIO')))`

Without an operator (I find this simplest):
`(and parent_post_content:'BRAZIL' (range field=post_date ['2016-02-16T08:13:26Z','2016-09-16T08:13:26Z'}) (or title:'RIO' excerpt:'RIO'))`

If that fails, can you post the complete query? I'd like to check that, for example, you're using the structured query parser since you mentioned you're new to CloudSearch.

Here are some relevant docs from Amazon:

- [Compound queries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html) for more on the various operators
- [Searching text](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-phrases) for specifics on the phrase operator

Comment: Apparently the problem was not with the query, but with the displayed content. I foolishly trusted that the content displaying in the CloudSearch site was complete, and so concluded that it does not contain Brazil. But alas, it is not the full content, and when i check the full content, Brazil was there.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was not with the query, but with the displayed content. I foolishly trusted that the content displaying in the CloudSearch site was complete, and so concluded that it does not contain Brazil. But alas, it is not the full content, and when i check the full content, Brazil was there.

Sorry for the foolery.